# SharePoint 2016 Hardware requirements to include excel services

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, office-online-server

We are planning to migrate from sharepoint 2013 to sharepoint 2016.We have excelservices configured in sharepoint 2013.

1.While migrating to Sharepoint 2016 set up , are the following specs correct?
a.Web/App server
b.SQl server
c.Office online server (is this mandatory for viewing excels in browser)

2.Should office online server be on a separate server with only office web apps installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Office Online Server as a single-server farm, or as a multi-server, load-balanced farm. You can use physical servers or virtual machines.

This is stated by Microsoft but i recommend using a separate server and configuring it as Office Online Server because of this .

Here are a few things to be aware of when you install Office Online Server.

**Don't install any other server applications on the server that's running Office Online Server. This includes Exchange Server, SharePoint Server, Skype for Business Server, and SQL Server. If you have a shortage of servers, consider running Office Online Server in a virtual machine on one of the servers you have.**

Don't install any services or roles that depend on the Web Server (IIS) role on port 80, 443, or 809 because Office Online Server periodically removes web applications on these ports.

Don't install any version of Office. If it's already installed, you'll need to uninstall it before you install Office Online Server.

Don't install Office Online Server on a domain controller. It won't run on a server with Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS).